# Is fullscreenchange event supported in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried onFullScreenChange in React but it doesn't work, so I have to use addEventListener for my case, I wonder whether fullscreenchange event is supported in React ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

There is no `onFullScreenChange`, you can see all supported events in [related docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events).

You can check an example of [`useFullscreenStatus`](https://github.com/Darth-Knoppix/example-react-fullscreen/blob/master/src/utils/useFullscreenStatus.js) implementation to use it in custom hook:

```
export default function useFullscreenStatus(elRef) {
  const [isFullscreen, setIsFullscreen] = React.useState(
    document[getBrowserFullscreenElementProp()] != null
  );

  const setFullscreen = () => {
    if (elRef.current == null) return;

    elRef.current
      .requestFullscreen()
      .then(() => {
        setIsFullscreen(document[getBrowserFullscreenElementProp()] != null);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setIsFullscreen(false);
      });
  };

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.onfullscreenchange = () =>
      setIsFullscreen(document[getBrowserFullscreenElementProp()] != null);

    return () => {document.onfullscreenchange = undefined};
  });

  return [isFullscreen, setFullscreen];
}

function getBrowserFullscreenElementProp() {
  if (typeof document.fullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "fullscreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.mozFullScreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "mozFullScreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.msFullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "msFullscreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.webkitFullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "webkitFullscreenElement";
  } else {
    throw new Error("fullscreenElement is not supported by this browser");
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot :)

Comment: Its working in everywhere but in ios safari its getting error , fullscreenElement is not supported by this browser. @ Dennis any idea on this, it will be helpful for newbie

Comment: We are removing the listener function on the return function. So,
if I have 2 elements using the same hook in the same page, and 1 of them is unmounted, won't it detach the listener for the other?

Comment: Ofc it do, you need to sync total listeners for this specific event

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's nothing in [React repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/search?q=onFullScreenChange) with that identifier.

Comment: There are two scripts about that event 
https://github.com/facebook/react/search?q=FullScreenChange
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d4d1dc085d1332fdd5025c292adcb5b39811e5b5/packages/react-dom/src/events/DOMEventNames.js#L52
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4175f05934d3954827c00b7633c1ce8e4e87d227/packages/react-dom/src/events/ReactDOMEventListener.js#L464

Though it might be due to React updates throughout years.